# Using Ranges as Input for User Defined Function

Tags: excel, function, range, defined

I am trying to write a user defined function that allows me to select two ranges. These ranges are then used to test whether the average of the values in column B is larger or smaller than the weighted averages of values in Column B with weights in column A. The function then returns the larger of the two values to the cell where I input my UDF.

The code I have so far:

```
Function AVERAGES(RANGE1 As RANGE, RANGE2 As RANGE)
    If Application.WorksheetFuncion.Average(RANGE2) > ((Application.WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(RANGE1, RANGE2) / (Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(RANGE1)))) Then
        AVERAGES = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(RANGE2)
    Else
        AVERAGES = (Application.WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(RANGE1, RANGE2) / Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(RANGE1))
    End If
End Function
```

It does not return any errors with the code, however the cell in which I type it in to says `"#VALUE!`".

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try debugging your function by calling it from a separate Sub instead of from the worksheet.

Comment: Fix your typo here `Application.WorksheetFuncion.Average(RANGE2)` It worked for me then

Comment: Cheers brettdj, nice o know I had my code right, just missed a spelling mistake.

Comment: Question issues was a simple typo